# How To: Use MVC and Ajax to add / remove a row in grid for data entry + model binding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, grid, inline-editing

I'm new to Ajax, but I think I know how to reasonably use MVC + model binding.

What I'm trying to do is to create an Add button (or Ajax.ActionLink) to add a new row in my grid for data entry. Example: Think of a typical Order entry system with Order (header) and Product (items). My OrderViewModel contains an "Order" object, and the Order object contains a collection List.

The way I plan to do this is that my View render the grid in a PartialView, and the PartialView is a simple for-loop to create the table  tags from the List. I will use the default model binder (for collections).

Anyone have suggestions on how to do this?

I've already figured out how to do this using jQuery, but I want (i think I want) to try and use Ajax so that I can add my custom business logic (e.g. like setting defaults, translations, etc.)as opposed to do this client-side.

In other words, I want to do do something similar to what the Telerik grid does with its Ajax Editing with the Add/Remove link/buttons.

Tips and sample code would be greatly appreciated.

One of my challenges, and not sure if I'm going down the wrong way, is that I don't know how to pass back the model back to the Controller Action from the Ajax submit. When I look at Telerik's code, it looks like they store the persisted items in HttpContext.Session, and this is exactly the reason why I don't want to use their grid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They might choose the session repository storage for demonstration purposes. If you transform the logic from their SessionProductRepository class for your model and implement identical Update/Insert/Delete methods for it, you'll probably get what you want.